# fetch data from twitter when login

Tags: ios, swift, api, twitter

i want to make app that login with twitter so i want to fetch some data from twitter account such as id,username, and email.

i have an api that take the 3 parameters and return success so i want to get the 3 parameters.

i have a custom button and i want when i tap this button i want to get twitter page and after i write username and password i want to fetch data

i configure twitter and fabric account.

i only want a function to fetch this data for me.

thanks in advance

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    Fabric.with([TWTRTwitter.self])


    // twitter configration

    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"----------", consumerSecret:"-------")


    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data from twitter by using following method:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn { (session, error) in

            if (session != nil) {                
                let credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: (session?.authToken)!, secret: (session?.authTokenSecret)!)

                let username = session?.userName
                let userId = session?.userID

                print("Username: \(username ?? "")")
                print("UserId: \(userId ?? "")")


                let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
                client.requestEmail(forCurrentUser: { (email, error) in
                    if error == nil{
                        if email != nil{
                            let email = email
                            print("Email: \(email ?? "")")
                        }
                    }else{
                        print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                    }
                })

            }else{
                print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: why you write credential also you do not use it ?

Comment: and why i get this error ?   objc[5534]: Class TWTRAppAuthProvider is implemented in both /Users/mohamedeldewaik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/39D130B2-2965-41AA-838A-0DC6A608328B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1B22A364-6ABA-442F-990F-A2673C9AC12F/Garage.app/Frameworks/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit (0x1073da548) and /Users/mohamedeldewaik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/39D130B2-2965-41AA-838A-0A2673C9AC12F/Garage.app/Frameworks/TwitterCore.framework/TwitterCore (0x107252370). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: Only use TwitterKit framework rather than both and then check. May be you will not get this error.

Comment: I have write credential to show you that you use this as further for other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Declare variable:**

```
var twiterUserdata: [String:Any] = [:]
```

**function for get user Info:**

```
 func twitterUserInfo(){
        TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(completion: { (session, error) in
            let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
            client.requestEmail { emailId, error in
                if (emailId != nil) {
                    let name = session?.userName
                    let email = emailId
                    self.twiterUserdata["name"] = name
                    self.twiterUserdata["email"] = email
                    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()
                    print(self.arrTwiterUserdata)
                } else {
                    print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Hope It's helps to you.!!